# Please teach the construction law of oracle $U_f$ in Grover’s algorithm

Tags: grovers-algorithm

[image: ![image|690x196](upload://4duiwxn09NE1l4cRcdrgo1OATc8.png)]

The framework of Grover's algorithm is shown in Figure from Qiskit.
https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-algorithms/grovers-algorithm

But I didn't understand the tutorial's construction rules for $U_f$. If there are four qubits, labeled 0001, 0010, 1001, and 1110, how to design $U_f$?  If there are 5 bits, labeled 00101, 01010, 10101, and 11110, how to design $U_f$? Can you summarize in code how Uf imposes  CZ gates?

[image: @CatalinaAlbornoz]

Also, what is the difference between a Phase Oracle and a Boolean Oracle[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8f6F.png)?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8f6F.png) C. Figgatt, D. Maslov et al., “Complete 3-qubit Grover search on a programmable quantum computer,” Nature Communications, vol. 8, no. 1, pp. 1918, 2017.
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01904-7

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $f(x)$ which takes an $n$ bit input and gives a 1 bit output. The phase oracle does the following:
$$
|x\rangle\mapsto (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle
$$
acting on $n$ qubits.

The Boolean oracle acts on $n+1$ qubits as
$$
|x\rangle|y\rangle\mapsto |x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle.
$$
Note that it is easy to construct the phase oracle out of the Boolean oracle by using the "phase kick-back", supplying the extra qubit in the state $|0\rangle-|1\rangle$:
$$
|x\rangle(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)\mapsto(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle(|0\rangle-|1\rangle).
$$

I generally find it a lot easier to think about how to construct a Boolean oracle (then I can use the equivalence between oracles to construct the phase oracle if necessary). Imagine I want to mark a set of binary strings $\{z\}$. At worst case, I can take them one at a time, construct a Boolean oracle for each one, and run them one after the other.

So, what does a Boolean oracle look like for a single marked state $z$? I apply $X$ to all the qubits which have bit value 0 in $z$, so that now my marked state has been converted into the all-ones. Then I do a controlled-controlled-...-controlled-not targetting the one extra qubit. So, it has been flipped if I was in the marked state. Then I just repeat all the $X$ operations that I did before.

What does the phase oracle look like? I just replace the controlled-controlled-...-not with a controlled-controlled-...-controlled-phase acting only on the $n$ qubits, not the ancilla.

For example, below we have $n=4$, marking the state $z=1001$, for the Boolean and phase oracles.
[image]

Comment: But the phase Orcle in the diagram uses Z gates and controlled Z gates, which don't match the gates you're using, are they equivalent?

Comment: ? His last circuit is meant to indicate that the CX oracle is equivalent to a CZ oracle with one fewer qubit. The C..Z gates are symmetric, your circuits had them as a control then a Z gate but Daftwullie’s didn’t because CC..Z is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I still didn't understand how to deploy X gates and multiple controllable CNOT gates if marking multiple target state cases?

Comment: In fact I would like to deploy Uf circuits labeling arbitrarily many target states at arbitrary quantum bits on Qiskit via a python program, but I don't know what laws Z-gates and controllable Z-gates are deployed according to.

Comment: This means that I wasn't able to generalize the mathematical rules for the arrangement of the phase Orcle in Figure 2.

Comment: You just apply them one after the other.

Comment: The phase oracle circuits in the diagram you give benefit from some rearrangement. For two-qubit controlled-phase gates, you can work out how an $X$ gate can be moved through - it stays as an $X$ on the qubit to which it is applied, and performs a $Z$ on the other qubit. Then the $X$ that has moved through cancels with the $X$ that was already on the other side, just leaving the $Z$. But these sorts of optimisations are specific to certain circuits, where the method I gave you was general (but can often be improved for a specific case).

Comment: I'm confused about the second phase Oracle, is it only the control bit for entanglement? Or is it another special quantum gate.

Comment: do you mean the controlled-controlled-..-controlled-Z gate?